# Bootstrap footer centrar contenido

Tags: bootstrap

Hola buenas tengo este footer hecho con bootstrap

```html
<footer class="text-muted py-2 mt-2 container-fluid p-1">
    <div class="row container-fluid justify-content-center">
       <div class="redes-sociales col-lg-4 col-md-12 justify-content-center p-2 mx-auto ">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/soypersonahumana/" class="facebook"  target=”_blank”><span class="fab fa-facebook"  target=”_blank”></span></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/igpersonahumana/" class="instagram"  target=”_blank”><span class="fab fa-instagram"  target=”_blank”></span></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jorge-mart%C3%ADnez-ruiz-49789978/?originalSubdomain=es" class="linkedin"  target=”_blank”><span class="fab fa-linkedin"></span></a>

      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 justify-content-center align-items-center d-flex pt-2">
        <p>Designed by <a class="nacho" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ignacio-mediero-d%C3%ADaz-919427140/?originalSubdomain=es"  target=”_blank”>Ignacio Mediero Díaz</a></p>
      </div>        
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 justify-content-center pt-2">
      
        <a href="pag/politica.html" class="text-dark float-right" >*Política de Privacidad</a>
        
      </div>    
     
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Mi problema es que no puedo centrar los contenidos de los div hago cuando responsive. Me da igual que sea con mediaqueries
Podriais echarme una mano??

Comment: serías tan amable de indicar que versión de bootstrap usas?

Comment: Porque asignas un col-lg-4 al footer? Estás pensando añadir más contenido a las columnas que te restan?

Answer (score -1):

Suponiendo que estés usando Bootstrap 4:

Te ha faltado añadir el d-flex en el segundo div ( y además tenías una etiqueta de cierre en el primero que sobraba)

```
<div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 justify-content-center align-items-center d-flex pt-2">
        <p>Designed by <a class="nacho" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ignacio-mediero-d%C3%ADaz-919427140/?      originalSubdomain=es" target=”_blank”>Ignacio Mediero Díaz</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 justify-content-center d-flex pt-2">
        <a href="pag/politica.html" class="text-dark float-right">*Política de Privacidad</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aquí tienes un Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cr6sqgL8/

Un saludo!

Comment: ¿Porqué hay un voto negativo si en el Fidle se ve que la solución funciona?